# Rails Paperclip Image location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm working on a website, doing some rails work, and I've run into a problem.

The way things work, I have user model, and a buy account type model, and I'm trying to use paperclip to set up profile pictures. The problem is, when I take in the photo, it puts it into an asset folder for the user model, and tries to load it from a buyer model folder. I've tried to to use the path and url to change the location, and it all looks right, but it's still not working.

Here's the code in my buyer model file

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "200x", :thumb => "100x100>" },
:default_url => "default.jpg",
:path => "/public/system/users/images/:id/:style/:basename.jpg",
:url => "/public/system/users/images/:id/:style/:basename.jpg"
```

and the view to show the profile

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>


<p>
 <%= image_tag @buyer.image.url(:medium) %>
</p>
<p>
 <strong>First name:</strong>
 <%= @buyer.firstname %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Last name:</strong>
  <%= @buyer.lastname %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Username:</strong>
  <%= @buyer.username %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Password:</strong>
  <%= @buyer.password %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_buyer_path(@buyer) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', buyers_path %>
```

Not really sure what's wrong. When viewing the source for the page, the URL for the image looks right, but it still shows the missing image image.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: I got it working by removing the /public at the beginning, so now it's just /system...... but, now, when I make a new buyer account, it makes the folder differently. Where before it was just /users/ID, it's now /users/000/000/0ID. I don't know how I'm gonna do this.

Comment: It looks like absolute paths. Are **100** percent sure you want that?

Comment: I got it working by removing the /public at the beginning, so now it's just /system...... but, now, when I make a new buyer account, it makes the folder differently. Where before it was just /users/ID, it's now /users/000/000/0ID. I don't know how I'm gonna do this.

Comment: @user2816254 if you are not married to `paperclip` take a look at `carrierwave`. I find to much easier to maintain since you actually create classes to handle the uploads.